# Trouble Using Heatmap.js Data Points

Tags: javascript, heatmap

Hi I know not many people know heatmap.js but im not even sure if its an issue with that or just my code. I have the following code to create my data points:

```
pointsArray = []
for (i = 0; i < numberValuesInArray; i++) { 
    points = {x: xAxis[i], y: yAxis[i], value: (count[i] / average * 100)};
    pointsArray.push(points);
}
```

This part is working fine, it is in the correct format. The following code doesnt work:

```
var dataPoints = {
    min: -50,
    max: 150,  
    data: [pointsArray]
};
```

Inside the data part it doesnt accept the entire array which is what i need it to do to display all the data points. If I put:

```
var dataPoints = {
    min: -50,
    max: 150,  
    data: [pointsArray[1]]
};
```

This code works when I just call a specific index inside of the array but i need to be able to call the entire array. Thank you for your help in advanced :)

Comment: pointsArray is a list. You're doing a list of list. Try this : data: pointsArray

Comment: Im such an idiot thank you so much ahahah

Comment: No man, you're not. This kind of things happen when learning and sometimes we take some hours to find a little error. Glad it helped! =)